Use emulated COM serial port with Printer emulator
As I don't have a thermal printer, I've opted in for using an emulator. I'm currently using VSPE to emulate a pair of COM ports (COM2 and COM5), and then running the emulator for Bematech MP-4200. It runs perfectly. I've used WinTFI2 RAT to send commands to the printer, and it worked fine.
Problem is, for some reason, when I try to send text to print from my python code, I receive errors saying I'm not allowed to use the port.
This kind of confused me, because the printer is connected as expected in the port COM2, but when I access it to send data it says I'm not allowed.
As for the code, I've tried three approaches.
Option 1 - First one (and the one I would prefer) , contained on the file min-test.py is:
from escpos import SerialConnection
from escpos.impl.epson import GenericESCPOS

conn = SerialConnection.create('COM2:9600,8,1,N')
printer = GenericESCPOS(conn)
printer.init()
printer.text('----> Printer Test')

If I run it with the printer emulator off, I get no message. If the printer emulated is on, I receive the following error message:
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM2': PermissionError(13, 'Access denied.', None, 5)
Option 2 - min-test-2.py runs the following code:
import os, serial
import pty, tty
from termios import *

master, slave = pty.openpty()
s_name = os.ttyname(slave)

ser = serial.Serial('COM2')

# To Write to the device
ser.write('Your text')

# To read from the device
os.read(master,1000)

For this I receive:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'
Option 3 - serial-test.py runs the following code:
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM2', 115200)
if not ser.isOpen():
    ser.open()
print('com2 is open', ser.isOpen())

And for that I get the same error than the first:
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM2': PermissionError(13, 'Access Denied.', None, 5)
Anyone knows how to communicate with this virtual printer?
Github issue: https://github.com/rodhoff/pycoupon/issues/1
